# How to create Java objects from XML tags which are referring each other?

Tags: java, xml, spring, jaxb, jibx

I have an XML which has tags corresponding to three types of Java objects which would be created from the XML. The objects are of the form:

```
A
- static Map<String, A>
- String name
- String aInfo1
- String aInfo2

B
- static Map<String, B>
- String name
- String bInfo1
- String bInfo2

C
- A aObject
- B bObject
```

Now, in my XML, I define a list of tags for A objects and B objects and then I define tags for C objects which refer to A and B objects using there name field.
I have two requirements:

1. populate static maps in A and B while reading the A and B objects from XMLs. The maps will contain a mapping of A.name to A, and B.name to B respectively.
2. populate C objects by reading the A.name and B.name from XML tag and then using the maps defined in A and B objects.

I have read about some Java frameworks like JAXB but I am unable to come up with a way to create such type of objects from my XML. Is there a framework in Java which can do this out-of-the box or with minimum logic?

Edit:

There is another requirement:
I need to define D and E objects of the form

```
D
- Map<A, E>
```

I would define E objects similar to how servlets are defined in web.xml i.e. first define the name and class for the E class and then use the name for E at some other place. Additionally, pass parameters to instantiate E objects. The tag would look like:

```
<E>
    <name>queryProcessor</name>
    <class>com.mydomain.QueryProcessor</class>
</E>
```

Now this would be used while defining content of Map in D

```
<D>
    <map>
        <A>name_of_some_A_object</A>
        <E name="queryProcessor">
            <param1>name_of_some_B_object</param1>
            <param2>name_of_some_B_object</param2>
        </E>
        <A>name_of_some_A_object</A>
        <E name="queryProcessor">
            <param1>name_of_some_B_object</param1>
            <param2>name_of_some_B_object</param2>
        </E>
     </map>
 </D>
```

Essentially the map in D will be populated by instantiating a class of base type E with the parameters passed to it and an object of A, referred by its name.

Comment: about how large is that XML? (if its smaller than about 20MB you can use simpler structures than when its larger)

Comment: Unfortunately "static" does not have a good translation to XML.

Comment: it's quite small, it will populate around 10 to 20 A and B objects, and around 20-25 C objects. Less than 100k i would guess

Comment: For sucha a simple structure, it's much simpler to just do it yourself: use XPath and populate the objects.

Comment: I agree, but this is just the beginning. Plenty of other complex cases would come up as my XML will evolve. I was hoping to find something which can allow to hook up some logic at a few places while handling the rest.

Comment: Please tell us why you think you need this XML. There might be better options (e.g. Spring).

Comment: Are you talking about the format of the XML? Or why I need XML at all? I need XML for the ability to make my applications configurable outside of Java.

Comment: How does spring come into the picture?

Comment: With Spring you can configure which beans you want to create.

Comment: @Ashish, if all you are trying to do is to make your app configurable, Puce is right - you should consider using Spring. Generally speaking, you could use a parser like JAXB or Castor or JiBX - basically bind information onto java objects and then iterate and fill the maps. I would have actually written my own SAX based parser and filled the objects esp. given the dynamics involved. Again, I would very strongly recommend the Spring framework for your purpose.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Specify the correct XML format with an XSD
- Generate the JAXB classes

(You could do it also the other way around, if you are familiar with JAXB annotations and want to control the interface with Java rather than with an XSD).

Note: static Maps is most likely not what you want to use. If you explain more about what problem you want to solve we might be able to point you out some alternative ways

Edit:

> Are you talking about the format of the XML? Or why I need XML at all? I need XML for the ability to make my applications configurable outside of Java.

It looks like you're re-inventing the wheel. Have a look at Spring and see if it fits your needs. If it doesn't, explain why.

Comment: The static Map is required to lookup objects of type A using their name. This is useful for populating other objects like C and D.

Comment: You might need a singleton of some sorts, but a static Map will get you in problems sooner or later in most cases.

Comment: how would I initialise classes of type E using JAXB?

Comment: If you want to read the XML then use an Unmarshaller: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/xml/bind/JAXBContext.html#createUnmarshaller()

Comment: just reading the XML is not what I am looking for. I need to read the XML and populate my objects in a very specific way, as I have mentioned in my question. Is that possible with JAXB?

Comment: Optimize the XSD for data storage, read it (e.g. using JAXB), process it (working on JAXB Java objects rather than on XML) to optimize it for further processing.

Comment: Could you please explain it in terms of the XML I have specified and the Java object which I need to create. I know the general process of working with JAXB but have no idea how to model it according to my requirements. For instance, the part where I need to read the class name from XML and then initialise that class with the supplied parameters.

Comment: Having looked at Spring for some time now, I believe my current set of requirements can be met by using Spring. Could you please help me in identifying some of the things which I can't do with Spring as compared to JAXB in order to be able to make a decision on whether to use Spring or JAXB?

Answer (score 1):

From what you describe this could be done with a common framework such as Spring, either by you changing your XML or generate a XSTL which creates a Spring XML config file from your XML.

[Spring Core documentation](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.0.RC1/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html) is probably enough to get you started. An example of the XML would be

```
<bean id="beanOneId" class="the.bean.Class">
    <property name="someProperty" value="staticValue">
    <property name="someOtherProperty" ref="beanTwoId">
</bean>
<bean id="beanTwoId" class="the.otherbean.Class">
    <property name="someOtherProperty" ref="beanOneId">
    <property name="someOtherProperty" ref="beanThreeId">
</bean>
```

But what you describe should not be too hard with reflection. Assuming that none of the other objects need a reference in the constructor (but rather as setX) I would start by scanning the xml, create and store all objects with their names and remember a list of "connections" so be made. After all objects are created do all connections in the connection list.

Comment: how can this be done through Spring? What changes are required to be made in my XML. I can change the XML format completely if required.

Comment: If you look at Spring Core there are examples for wiring beans together, and the can reference each other. I'll add an example of how that would look in the answer.

Comment: define each instance of A, B, C, D, E as a bean in spring definition, and inject appropriate values. You can manage the structure as you like, even populate the maps!

Comment: that sounds weird, how can I make each instance of A,B... as a bean. AFAIK it's good to have beans which are instances of different classes. Also, how would I make sure that a new instance for the type E is created each time they are accessed.

Comment: If A or B does not take arguments in the constructor and they have get/set methods, then you are good to go. if you set the attribute scope="prototype" on your bean definition in the xml, then you will get a new instance each time you request that bean.

Comment: Please help me in identifying things u can do through JAXB but not with Spring, to enable me to make a decision on whether Spring will be appropriate choice for my application.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you want to have a look at XStream: http://x-stream.github.io/

It is a good library to marshal and unmarshal objects to and from XML, and does nothing more (unlike Spring). Like example in http://x-stream.github.io/tutorial.html, You can load objects from XML as easy as:

```
Person newJoe = (Person)xstream.fromXML(xml);
```

In order for XStream to understand your XML, you need to setup some alias like http://x-stream.github.io/alias-tutorial.html described.

XStream alone will not be able to solve your problem completely, mainly due to the two static maps. However you can let XStream to load a list of As and Bs from the XML, then build the two maps from the list.

For object C referencing A and B, you can read the following tutorial talking about object reference: http://x-stream.github.io/graphs.html. If it does not suit your need, you can always easily build another Class to read necessary information from XML using XStream, like

```
public class CInfo {
    public String aName;
    public String bName
}
```

And construct C instances using CInfo. Given you already have name to instance map of A and B, it will be trivial.

Comment: I could not find how it would map to my requirement. If you have used it, then can you please let me know how I would use XStream to do what I have mentioned in my question.

Comment: @Ashish XStream is able to create an object / objects from a XML file, base on your class definition. Like illustrated by http://xstream.codehaus.org/tutorial.html and http://xstream.codehaus.org/alias-tutorial.html. However, I do not think it will solve your problem completely, mainly due to the static field requirement. I will modify my answer to give more details.

Comment: @Ashish I do not think any framework or library can do everything. However, XStream appears to be the easier option (comparing to JAXB or Spring, which I had some bad experience with)