# What is it that you can't do in Spring?

Tags: java, xml, spring, jaxb

I am evaluating the use of XML configurations for our applications and I have some basic requirements as mentioned in [this stackoverflow link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8358791/how-to-create-java-objects-from-xml-tags-which-are-referring-each-other)

As per that discussion, it seems my requirements can be met by JAXB or Spring (perhaps, I need to write lesser amount of code in Spring). But I am not convinced about using Spring since my requirements are expected to grow (which is true for every application not just mine :-))

Keeping that in mind, I am inclined to go with JAXB, so that I am able to extend my XML in any way I require. But as of now I am not able to think about the kind of use case where Spring will fail me.

Could someone please share their experience of some scenarios where Spring does not provide enough flexibility and scenarios where JAXB would be much much better off to use.

Comment: There's some room for opinion here which is a no-no, but otherwise a well written question.  +1.  I have a lot of experience with Spring but none with JAXB so I can't comment.

Comment: I couldn't disagree more: This question makes no sense at all.

Answer (score 1):

JAXB and Spring feel like chalk and cheese to me.

JAXB takes an XML stream and generates Java Beans from it.

Spring is a three-legged framework based on dependency injection, aspect-oriented programming, and modules for features such as persistence, web MVC, etc.

I'd read up on both; you shouldn't be comparing them as either/or.  Spring is far, far more than JAXB.

Comment: If you look at the linked-two question, OP is basically trying to replicate Spring's bean configuration and seems to have tentatively decided to use JAX-B for it.

Comment: I agree with that, and we do use Spring for its other features. But my comparison is solely on the basis of the use of these for creating configurable objects in my application. So, it essentially boils down to the question that if you had similar requirements as mine (please refer to the earlier question), then which framework would you use to achieve the same and why?

Comment: or another way of asking could be: why would you ever use JAXB when Spring is offering you all the functionality of mapping XML to Java objects and many other additional features?

Comment: But JAXB is using introspection to do it; Spring is using what you have in the application context.  You have to add all the possibilities into Spring before you start.  Still not the same thing.

Comment: Still you haven't answered my question :)  If you were to use one of them for configuring my app (as mentioned in the other question), which one would you use and why?

Comment: I would use Spring - JAXB wouldn't cut it.

Answer (score 1):

If it is the question of loading config and starting your app (and only this requirement) then you can go with JAXB, but if there are requirements where you need to configure your app to interact with other services or make your app use DI (in the future) then spring is the way to go.

you can use both JAXB and spring togather but (if you use jaxb to load config as java objects) spring can be used to setup java objects with values using xml.

there is really no true way to compare the two frameworks (i have to agree with @duffymo on that) as they are intended for different things.

all in all, I'd suggest you to use spring (because of all the features which you can use, if needed) and simply because of the ease it brings into the development.

Comment: This is more of loading the config but even loading the config involves using one of the Spring injected objects. One of the objects I need to insert in the HashMap is currently coming from Spring DI.