# How to generate a static hashmap using JAXB?

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

Is it possible to generate a static hashmap using an XML schema with JAXB. If yes, then please specify what that schema will look like.

Comment: Are you trying to write XML which will unmarshal into a hashmap? If so, what are the types in your hashmap? Is it String to String? Or something else? (Or have I misunderstood the question entirely?)

Comment: yes, I need to write an XML which would unmarshal to a static hashmap in the generated class. It would be Map<String, MyClass> and it will be contained in MyClass itself. My main objective is to create objects of MyClass and put them in the static Hashmap in the same class mapping to their name

Comment: Is the static `HashMap` required for reasons other than sorting out object relationships (based on your related question:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8358791/how-to-create-java-objects-from-xml-tags-which-are-referring-each-other).  If so the following strategy may work better for you:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5319024/using-jaxb-to-cross-reference-xmlids-from-two-xml-files/5327425#5327425